# Polymorphic relation not inserting model type in database

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations

In my Laravel application, I have different models that can be reported so I am using a polymorphic relationship. Posts, Threads and solutions are reportable and can be MorphedToMany. When I try to create a new report in my controller I get `` General error: 1364 Field 'reportable_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `reports` (`channel`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ({"id":18,"created_at":"2020-08-20T09:37:06.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-08-20T09:37:06.000000Z","name":"marketing"}, 2020-08-21 09:13:45, 2020-08-21 09:13:45)) `` as an error

I followed the documentation the tutorial but I can't spot the error

here is my code with the post class as an example

post

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cog\Contracts\Love\Reactable\Models\Reactable as ReactableContract;
use Cog\Laravel\Love\Reactable\Models\Traits\Reactable;

class Post extends Model implements ReactableContract
{
    /**
     * @var mixed
     */

    use Reactable;

    protected $fillable=['title','body'];
    protected $guarded=[];

    public  function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
    public function channel(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Channel');
    }
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
    public function reports(){
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Report','reportable');
    }
}
```

report

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function reportable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

reportController

```
use App\Comment;
use App\Post;
use App\Report;
use App\Solution;
use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){

        switch (\request('table')){
            case 'posts':
                $model=Post::find(\request('model'));
                break;
            case 'threads':
                $model=Thread::find(\request('model'));
                break;

            case 'solutions':
                $model=Solution::find(\request('model'));
                //for now we are not implementing comments since is gonna be more complicated
        }

        //save model into database
        $report=new Report();
        $report->channel=$model->channel->name;
        $model->reports()->create(['channel'=>$model->channel]);
        //notify user
        //redirect to channel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved I used `MorphToMany` instead of `MorphMany`